# Declaring an object in header file

Tags: c++

I created a class called coordinate
I want to create a vector of coordinate objects called `cooPos` to use it in another class called `ScribbleArea`. (It is from a Qt Example). 
For some reason I always get the error:

> error: `cooPos` was not declared in this scope

coordinates.h

```
#ifndef COORDINATE_H
#define COORDINATE_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class coordinate
{
public:
    coordinate(float y, float x, bool isPressed);
    float get_x();
    float get_y();
    std::string get_coordinateText();


private:
    float x_pos;
    float y_pos;
    bool isPressedState;
};

#endif // COORDINATE_H
```

coordinate.cpp

```
#include "coordinate.h"

coordinate::coordinate(float y, float x, bool isPressed)
{
    y_pos = y;
    x_pos = x;
    isPressedState = isPressed;
}


std::string coordinate::get_coordinateText()
{
    std::string output;
    output = "X: " + std::to_string(x_pos) + " Y: " + std::to_string(y_pos) +"\n";
    return output;
}

float coordinate::get_x()
{
    return x_pos;
}

float coordinate::get_y()
{
    return y_pos;
}
```

scribblearea.h

```
#ifndef SCRIBBLEAREA_H
#define SCRIBBLEAREA_H

#include <QColor>
#include <QImage>
#include <QPoint>
#include <QWidget>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "coordinate.h"



class ScribbleArea : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ScribbleArea(QWidget *parent = 0);


private:

    void addCoordinate(float x, float y, bool isPressed);


    std::vector<coordinate> cooPos;


};

#endif
```

scribbleare.cpp

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#ifndef QT_NO_PRINTER
#include <QPrinter>
#include <QPrintDialog>
#endif

#include "scribblearea.h"

ScribbleArea::ScribbleArea(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_StaticContents);

}


void addCoordinate(float x, float y, bool isPressed)
{

    coordinate *actPos = new coordinate(y,x,isPressed);
    cooPos.push_back(*actPos);
}
```

I have really no idea...

Comment: Replace `addCoordinate` by `ScribbleArea::addCoordinate`.

Comment: Thank you, that solves my problem! Should have seen it by myself...